# How can I recursively go to every folders and execute shell script with the same name?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, recursion, gnu-findutils

I have this directory.

```
.
├── animation
│   ├── animation-events
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── app.mustache.json
│   │   ├── create_view.sh
│   │   └── assets
│   │       └── dummy_character_sprite.png
│   └── change-frame
│       ├── app.js
│       ├── app.mustache.json
│       ├── create_view.sh
│       └── assets
│           └── dummy_character_sprite.png
├── app.css
├── app.mustache
├── bunch_of_functions.js
├── decorators.js
├── create_all_views.sh
└── displaying-a-static-image
    ├── app.js
    ├── app.mustache.json
    ├── create_view.sh
    └── assets
        └── piplup.png
```

I want for `create_all_views.sh` to execute all `create_view.sh` in the children directory. How can I achieve such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are in Ubuntu, you have the GNU implementation of `find`,
which has the `-execdir` option,
and you can do like this:

```
find path/to/dir -name create_view.sh -execdir ./create_view.sh \;
```

That is,
for each `create_view.sh` file it finds in the directory tree,
it will execute `./create_view.sh` in the directory of that file.

Comment: Great, what does `\;` used for?

Comment: The `\;` is used to indicate the end of the arguments to `-execdir`. You could for example have more options after it, as in `find path/to/dir -name create_view.sh -execdir ./create_view.sh \; -print -ls`

Comment: How can I execute more than one commands? I have `find $(dirname $0) -name create_view.sh -execdir chmod +x ./create_view.sh \ ./create_view.sh \;` but it returns, `No such file or directory` on `chmod +x` .

Comment: @notalentgeek with multiple `-execdir`, like this: `find $(dirname $0) -name create_view.sh -execdir chmod +x ./create_view.sh \; -execdir ./create_view.sh \;`